# in django SignupForm signup method is not being overrided

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have this working SignupForm in Django==1.10.6.

The form is working because when I change a label it gets reflected in the form, but the signup method is never executed.

I've been struggling with this for a while now, what am I missing here?

The output is never printed, the user is not saved properly and the ipdb module does not start.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit, HTML, Div
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import TabHolder, Tab, Accordion, AccordionGroup

from alistate.core.utils import LowerField

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as SignupFormBase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SignupForm(SignupFormBase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(Field('username'), css_class='col-md-12'),
                Div(Field('email'), css_class='col-md-12'),
                Div(Field('password1'), css_class='col-md-12'),
                Div(Field('password2'), css_class='col-md-12'),
            css_class='row'),
            Div(
                Div(Field('nombre1'), css_class='col-md-6'),
                Div(Field('apellido1'), css_class='col-md-6'),
            css_class='row'),
            Div(
                Div(Field('nombre2'), css_class='col-md-6'),
                Div(Field('apellido2'), css_class='col-md-6'),
            css_class='row'),
            Div(
                Div(Field('telefono'), css_class='col-md-12'),
            css_class='row'),
            Div(
                Div(Field('fecha_religiosa', css_class="datetimepicker-signup"), css_class='col-md-12'),
            css_class='row'),
            Div(
                Div(Field('como_conocio'), css_class='col-md-12 register-know'),
            css_class='row'),
        )

    nombre1 = LowerField(label="Nombreeee 1 (novia/o).", required=True, max_length=50)
    apellido1 = LowerField(label="Apellido 1 (novia/o).", required=True, max_length=50)
    nombre2 = LowerField(label="Nombre 2 (novia/o).", required=True, max_length=50)
    apellido2 = LowerField(label="Apellido 2 (novia/o).", required=True, max_length=50)
    fecha_religiosa = forms.DateTimeField(required=True)
    telefono = LowerField(label=u"Teléfono", required=True, max_length=50)
    como_conocio = forms.CharField(label=u"¿Cómo nos conociste?", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()   # or whatever your User model is

    def signup(self, request, user):
        print("yyehehehehe")
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        user.nombre1 = self.cleaned_data['nombre1']
        user.apellido1 = self.cleaned_data['apellido1']
        user.nombre2 = self.cleaned_data['nombre2']
        user.apellido2 = self.cleaned_data['apellido2']
        user.fecha_religiosa = self.cleaned_data['fecha_religiosa']
        user.telefono = self.cleaned_data['telefono']
        user.como_conocio = self.cleaned_data['como_conocio']
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: did you update the settings `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'mysite.forms.SignupForm'}`?

Answer (score 0):

By replacing **def signup** with **def signup** I was able to make it work

```
def save(self, request):
    user = super(SignupForm, self).save(request)
    user.nombre1 = self.cleaned_data['nombre1']
    user.apellido1 = self.cleaned_data['apellido1']
    user.nombre2 = self.cleaned_data['nombre2']
    user.apellido2 = self.cleaned_data['apellido2']
    user.celular = self.cleaned_data['celular']
    user.fecha_religiosa = self.cleaned_data['fecha_religiosa']
    user.telefono = self.cleaned_data['telefono']
    user.como_conocio = self.cleaned_data['como_conocio']
    user.save()
    return user
```